# NoClassDefFoundError android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I wont add materials animations i do all same like in this  [tutorial](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)

i create main activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupWindowAnimations();
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)
            findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
private void setupWindowAnimations() {
    Slide slide = new Slide();
    slide.setDuration(1000);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);
}
```

and create second activity
 `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        setupWindowAnimations();
    }
    private void setupWindowAnimations() {
        Fade fade = new Fade();
        fade.setDuration(1000);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
    }`

but when i start my app i get `NoClassDefFoundError`

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.transition.Slide
ua.com.alc.alcotaste E/AndroidRuntime:at ua.com.alc.alcotaste.MainActivity.setupWindowAnimations(MainActivity.java:54)
ua.com.alc.alcotaste E/AndroidRuntime:at ua.com.alc.alcotaste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)`

Comment: Did you declare your second activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Are you using API level 19 or higher? https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html